# How to load a mixed assembly that is registered in GAC?

Tags: .net, interop, .net-assembly

I posted this issue on MSDN, but it is a bit of wasting time by communicating to MS support, they only give you one sentence per day without any clue :(, anyway here is my question, appreciate any comments.

I am experiencing an assembly loading issue in my interop project

i.e. there are 3 VS projects:

- A is a native C project that references B via static binding, i.e. A invokes B's functions if you like;
- B is a CLI wrapper, which in turn statically references C's objects;
- C is a CS project which is purely .NET code.

Both B and C are signed with strong name, and their *AssemblyInfo.cs* and *AssemblyInfo.cpp* files are updated with their key files.

Both B and C are registered in GAC using *gacutil.exe V4.0*. A has a reference to B.dll from the folder where B.dll is registered, B has a reference to C in the same forlder where C is registered.

When I run the program from A, it fails with message:

> 'The program can't start because B.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling >the program to fix this problem'.

The only way I can make it working is copy B.dll to the same folder of A.exe. It seems C.dll is loaded from GAC ok.

Does mixed assembly work in different way in loading perspective?

Comment: By the way, it doesn't work either the copy local option true or false.

Comment: You `gacutil`'d B? Don't you need to `regsvr32` it, given it needs to be accessed from a non-CLI program?

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster. It is a good point I didn't think of, actually B doesn't need to be in GAC, as long as it is covered by PATH, all works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a bit of a hack to get the CLR loaded to execute the managed code.  Presumably you wrote static functions in the CLI code and decorated them with `__declspec(dllexport)`.  Yes, that works, the native code (A) can call through a stub that the C++/CLI compiler generated which ensures that the CLR is loaded and initialized.

What however cannot work is the CLR helping the find the DLL in the GAC.  That's a chicken-and-egg problem, the CLR has to be loaded before it can find assemblies.  So B finding C is no problem.  But A finding B isn't going to work.  It is the job of the native Windows loader to find B and it has no reason at all to look in the GAC.

You'll need to deploy B in the same folder as the native program.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant for all the explanation, it is clearer to me now, as soon as I included B'd folder in PATH it worked all fine.